# Jquery autocomplete doesnot work with mouse click but works fine with enter key in chrome and not at all in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, autocomplete

I have some isssue with the autocomplete.
My jquery autocomplete doesnot work with mouse click.. however in google chrome if i hit Enter key it fires and works fines whereas in exlporer it doesnt work with both mouse click and the enter key..here is my code..

```
$("#mp_search").autocomplete({
                    source: addedAccountsAutoCompleteSource,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $("#mp_search").val(ui.item.label);
                        selectedAccountId = ui.item.value;
                        console.log("selectedAccountId = " + selectedAccountId);
                    },
                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $("#mp-search").val(ui.item.label);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: why your code is inside quotes?

Comment: I dont know from where those quotes came there :D ... it is without the quotes and now i have already corrected